# How to update alarm by Canceling the old one and Adding new alarm?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

How to update an alarm time and date

```
Intent i = new Intent("com.appsinbox.mydiary.remainder.demoactivity");
PendingIntent operation = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(), 0, i, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(year,month,day, 7, 00);
long alarm_time = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP  , alarm_time , operation);
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Alarm is set successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Use the Flag FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT in your pending Intent.

Answer (score 0):

Just Call cancel method :-

**cancel**

```
mAlarmPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, requestCode, intent, flags);
this.getAlarmManager().cancel(mAlarmPendingIntent);
```

or

**add new**

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(alarm);

Intent i= new Intent("MY_INTENT");
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, i, 0);

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 2);
am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pi);
```